# How to get the JSON output as shown using Spring Rest Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a column mapped to variable as follows

`@Column(name = "VAL_ZIP")
   private String New_Zip;`

output in JSON is

`new_zip:45667`

but I want it as

`New_Zip:45677`

How to achieve this?

I also want to maintain the structure like I declared

`@Column(name = "VAL_ZIP")
   private String New_Zip;
@Column(name = "VAL_St")
   private String New_St;`

my output is

`new_St:CA
new_Zip:45677`

instead of

`new_Zip:45677
new_st:CA`

Comment: Why do you think Hibernate has anything to do with the names in JSON?

Comment: Hibernate is an ORM, its main purpose is persistence to database, it has nothing to do with JSON serialization(or pretty much any serialization)

Comment: can you tell us what json library are you using(if any) and show us the serialization code ?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question, but I am using Spring boot Rest for the API. I don't have any json library I am just returning the List. guide me how to do this if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field order within an object is never guaranteed. It looks like it is returning them in lexicographical (alphabetical) order.

Also, Java [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) state that you should use mixed-case for your instance fields.

> Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with capital letters. Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.

You can use the `JsonProperty` annotation in Jackson to provide a mapping for your JSON serialization.

```
@Column(name = "VAL_ZIP")
@JsonProperty("New_Zip")
private String newZip;

@Column(name = "VAL_St")
@JsonProperty("Val_St")
private String newSt;
```